# mouseenter and mouseleave event handling triggers mulitple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of javascript code that when I hover over a ul it will display the dropdown on the menu bar. My menu bar can be closed on click and can be open again on click again. My code is as follows:

```
$('li.dropdown').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    //stuff to do on mouse enter
    console.log('hi')
    $(this.children[0]).trigger('click'); //upon hover, displays the toggle menu
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
    console.log('bye')
    $(this.children[0]).trigger('click'); //closes the menu when not hover
    $(document.activeElement).blur(); //takes the focus away from the element so the blue background color wont stay
  }
})
```

So when i reload the page, and I click on my menubar to open and I hover over the dropdown, it works fine. In my console, I get 'hi' and then 'bye'. However, when I close the menu bar and open it back up again and I hover over the dropdown, nothing happens. The dropdown doesn't show up. This is because the click on the mouseenter function is triggering twice. I know this because in my console, I see 'hi'x2 and when i take my mouse off i get 'bye'x3. As i keep on repeating this process without refreshing my page, 'hi' and 'bye' increments by one. So it would be 'hi'x3 next followed by 'hi'x4. etc. Therefore the hover only works on odd number of clicks.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or share your html too?

Comment: You are binding the event when you open the dropdown. You only need to do it once when the page loads.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself, not just on jsfiddle or any other third-party site. Note that the editor provides a fiddle-like experience if you click the Code Snippet button (a page with `<>` on it).

Comment: @tcooc thank you so much! that fixed the problem. I originally thought that if i put this event handler when my menubar was open, then thats the only place it would run and when i close my navbar, it would go away.

Comment: Good to hear my guess was on point. I'm voting to close this question since it was "was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".